# Convert screen video from FBR to AVI

Tags: windows, video, media-converter

There is screen videos in FBR format recorded by [BB FlashBack Express](http://www.flashbackrecorder.com/express).

It supports export to AVI, but the problem is with quality and file size. When I export file to AVI using built-in codecs, the quality decreses and file becomes several times large.

At the moment I found some way to convert: first of all I export FBR to uncompressed AVI then reboot to Linux and convert that AVI by Transmageddon to other AVI using h264 codec (there is no settings, everything uses defaults).

As you see it's a very strange way, it requres additional time and a lot of free space on the hard drive. So my questions are:

1. What programs (including codecs) I need to install on clean Windows 7 with FlashBack Express Recorder, so that it'll let me export FBR to AVI with approximately same quality and size?

   Programs have to be free. Allowing of commercial usage is highly desirable.
2. What settings should I use for export from FBR?

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/515189/178988)

Comment: @unor, why do you think [tag:screen-recording] tag is extra if I need to organize export from screen recorder?

Comment: I think the [tag:screen-recording] tag should be used if you need a screen recording tool. But if I understand your question correctly, you already use such a tool and the tool you need recommendations for does not need any screen recording functionality.

Comment: @unor, right. I would've use tag [tag:screenvideo] instead as it affects creterias for compression and converter, but there are only [tag:screenshot] and [tag:screen-recording].